# how to give my WordPress menu page custom link

Tags: php, wordpress, function, menu, dashboard

I have created a menu page using `add_menu_page()` and now page link is admin.php?page=xxxx
,but I am using this page to show notifications using `add_action('admin_notices', 'any_name');` and in this any_name function I used  `if ( $pagenow == '' ) {}` to specify the page where the notification should appear , and  'pagenow' dont accept link like admin.php?page=xxxx ,I cant figure out how to do it .

Comment: How about you first of all make a simple debug output, to see what $pagenow actually _does_ contain in this specific case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pagenow` would have a value of `admin.php`, not `admin.php?page=xxxx`.

So, you could check if you're on a specific page like this:

```php
<?php
if ( 'admin.php' === $pagenow && 'xxxx' === $_GET['page'] ) {
  // Display the admin notice
}
```